# Mac outdent in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, command

I was wondering if you could tell me how to outdent on Mac in Jupyter notebook as I don't have a ] on the keyboard and I also download autopep8 but don't know how this works if you don't have the bracket. Otherwise, Shift + Tab just changes office space, but does not indent on the notebook.
Thanks a lot for your answer.
Best,
Sarah